# Can I install Edubuntu onto Pi?

Tags: linux

How can I install Edubuntu onto Pi without using a server or a windows/mac OS?

I have tried a lot of different things and I cant seem to find anything on youtube to help me with installing this OS onto the Pi.

Comment: So that leaves linux as the OS you want to install off? Surely it is a case of downloading the necessary image file and flashing it to a SD card?

Answer (score 5):

[Edubuntu's own download page](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/14.04.2/release/) only offers "i386" (aka. x86) and AMD64 (aka. x86-64) [ISAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set).  These are the ISAs used by processors in most desktop and laptop computers (one is 32-bit, the other 64-bit).

Unfortunately for you all models of Pi use some form of ARM ISA, the kind commonly used in smartphones and other mobile or embedded devices.

This is very normal.  Most GNU/Linux distributions do not have an ARM port; the ones that do are exceptions and will usually only work on the Pi 2 or 3.  Very few work on the A/B/+/0 models.

However, [this edubuntu page](https://wiki.edubuntu.org/ARM/RaspberryPi) does discuss installing regular Ubuntu (which does have an ARMv7+ port) on the Pi 2 or 3.

Comment: this may be outdated. https://wiki.edubuntu.org/ARM/RaspberryPi and then there's this https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/edubuntu-devel/2016-March/003888.html

Comment: @deltree Thx.  Edited to include that information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, lucky us! Go here:

https://wiki.edubuntu.org/ARM/RaspberryPi

(I'm just cleaning this up as I pass through. The main question is outdated, as in the comments by @deltree.)