# How do I install GNUzilla IceCat on a raspberry pi?

Tags: software-installation, raspbian-buster

I'm looking for a version of Mozilla Firefox for the raspberry pi that isn't so restrictive on it's use of the logo. So instead I would like to install GNU Icecat with the cute logo. I'm running raspbian buster on a raspberry pi 3B+.

### Attempts

- Following the instructions on the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IceCat) failed to produce an executable binary.

```sh
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnuzilla/60.3.0/icecat-60.3.0.en-US.gnulinux-x86_64.tar.bz2
```

Correctly saved the file.

```sh
sudo tar -xvf icecat* -C /usr/bin/icecat/installed
```

Correctly extracts it, but

```sh
$ sh /usr/bin/icecat/installed/icecat/icecat
/usr/bin/icecat/installed/icecat/icecat: 1: /usr/bin/icecat/installed/icecat/icecat: ELF: not found
/usr/bin/icecat/installed/icecat/icecat: 1: /usr/bin/icecat/installed/icecat/ice: not found
/usr/bin/icecat/installed/icecat/icecat: 2: /usr/bin/icecat/installed/icecat/icecat: @@@@@@0pp@p@@@����: not found
/usr/bin/icecat/installed/icecat/icecat: 1: /usr/bin/icecat/installed/icecat/icecat: cannot open �0�A3: No such file
/usr/bin/icecat/installed/icecat/icecat: 1: /usr/bin/icecat/installed/icecat/icecat: �@: not found
/usr/bin/icecat/installed/icecat/icecat: 10: /usr/bin/icecat/installed/icecat/icecat: ��A��
           ��AEE: not found
/usr/bin/icecat/installed/icecat/icecat: 2: /usr/bin/icecat/installed/icecat/icecat: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Am I doing something wrong? Am I wrong to assume that these Ubuntu instructions would work for other Debian like systems such as Raspbian?

Comment: This entire question has been changed to be more clear on the problem I was having and the steps I took to solve it. Sorry about that everyone.

Comment: Shameless plug: I'm [working](https://github.com/dimag0g/uxp) with the authors of Pale Moon browser to get a Raspberry Pi release approved. It's essentially a fork of Firefox 52, with old plugin support and back-ported recent security features. If you disable the official branding, you can build and distribute it as "New Moon".

Answer (score 1):

If I follow your commands, first I get an error massage `tar: /usr/bin/icecat/installed: Cannot open: No such file or directory`. First I had to create it with before unpacking the archive:

```
rpi ~$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/bin/icecat/installed
rpi ~$ sudo tar -xvf icecat* -C /usr/bin/icecat/installed
```

Now if I look at **icecat** with `file` I find:

```
rpi ~$ file /usr/bin/icecat/installed/icecat/icecat
/usr/bin/icecat/installed/icecat/icecat: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=d043e81b32b71a57818b9aa510aced22459e40d7, stripped
```

As you can see `icecat` is an executable ELF file so you cannot start it as shell script with `sh /usr/bin/icecat/installed/icecat/icecat` as you did. But the most imporant information is that it is a 64-bit executable compiled for X86 (intel proccesor). Neither a 64-bit program can run on a 32 bit operating system like Raspbian nor can an X86 program run on an ARM processor.

Comment: Hmm. There seem to be multiple binaries available at https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnuzilla/60.3.0/. Is there one that will work?

Comment: @fifn2 I don't know. I use firefox from the default repository.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I wrong to assume that these Ubuntu instructions would work for other Debian like systems such as Raspbian?

It's not the difference between Ubuntu and Debian and Raspbian; you can install Ubuntu or Debian on a Pi if you want, but those instructions will than not work any better then they did on Raspbian.

The problem is the type of CPU.  Executable code is compiled for specific [instruction set architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) (ISAs).  For example, there is x86-64, which that `tar.gz` file was labelled as.  This means it was compiled for the most commonly used ISA on desktops and laptops.

No model of Raspberry Pi is compatible with x86-64 executables.  They require code that is compiled for a range of ARM processors.  Further explanation here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/49809/5538

If you cannot find a pre-compiled icecat for the Pi, it might be possible to compile it yourself on the Pi from source code.  However, I recommend against this: Web browsers are big, complex things.  Compiling one on the Pi would likely take hours, and may require a bit of know how to make it through that successfully (meaning there is a good chance it would just fail in puzzling ways).